# Need a Linux command for below ouput

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed, awk, grep

```
Input_file

"5" '6' '7'

Final_file   should have 

5  "6" '7'
```

Need a one liner command

Comment: So did you try anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat test.txt
"5" '6' '7'

$ awk -F"[\"']" '{print $2 " \""$4"\"",q$6q}' q="'" test.txt
5 "6" '7'
```